# NLTK in Azure ML

Tags: python, nltk, azure-machine-learning-service

Folks,

I have the below code to create pos tagger in nltk implemented as an "Execute Python Script" in Azure ML. The problem is the script has to download *maxent_treebank_pos_tagger* every time. Commenting the line would throw the below error. I even tried downloading using nltk.download('all') but still it did not help.

```
"C:\\pyhome\\lib\\site-packages\\nltk\\data.py\", line 467, in find\r\n raise LookupError(resource_not_found)\r\nLookupError: \r\n**********************************************************************\r\n Resource 'taggers/maxent_treebank_pos_tagger/english.pickle' not\r\n found. Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:\r\n >>> nltk.download()\r\n Searched in:\r\n - 'C:\\\\Users\\\\Client/nltk_data'\r\n - 'C:\\\\nltk_data'\r\n - 'D:\\\\nltk_data'\r\n - 'E:\\\\nltk_data'\r\n - 'C:\\\\pyhome\\\\nltk_data'\r\n - 'C:\\\\pyhome\\\\lib\\\\nltk_data'\r\n - 'C:\\\\Users\\\\Client\\\\AppData\\\\Roaming\\\\nltk_data'\r\n**********************************************************************\r\nProcess returned with non-zero exit code 1\r\n\r\n---------- End of error message from Python interpreter ----------"}}Error: Error 0085: The following error occurred during script evaluation, please view the output log for more information:---------- Start of error message from Python interpreter ----------Caught exception while executing function: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\server\invokepy.py", line 199, in batch odfs = mod.azureml_main(*idfs) File "C:\temp\febff15ac9584d978d04d40f0c7bd565.py", line 32, in azureml_main tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens) File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\__init__.py", line 99, in pos_tag tagger = load(_POS_TAGGER) File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 605, in load resource_val = pickle.load(_open(resource_url)) File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 686, in _open return find(path).open() File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 467, in find raise LookupError(resource_not_found)LookupError: ********************************************************************** Resource 'taggers/maxent_treebank_pos_tagger/english.pickle' not found. Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource: >>> nltk.download() Searched in: - 'C:\\Users\\Client/nltk_data' - 'C:\\nltk_data' - 'D:\\nltk_data' - 'E:\\nltk_data' - 'C:\\pyhome\\nltk_data' - 'C:\\pyhome\\lib\\nltk_data' - 'C:\\Users\\Client\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data'**********************************************************************Process returned with non-zero exit code 1---------- End of error message from Python interpreter ---------- Process exited with error code -2
```

Below is my code in Azure ml

```
def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):
# import required packages
import pandas as pd
import nltk
import numpy as np
# tokenize the review text and store the word corpus
word_dict = {}
token_list = []
#nltk.download('all')
#nltk.download(info_or_id='punkt', download_dir='C:/users/client/nltk_data')
#nltk.download(info_or_id='maxent_treebank_pos_tagger', download_dir='C:/users/client/nltk_data')
for text in dataframe1["tweet_text"]:
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text.decode('utf8'))
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)


  # convert feature vector to dataframe object
dataframe_output = pd.DataFrame(tagged, columns=['Word', 'Type'])
return [dataframe_output]
```

Comment: You need to download the tagger just once (just the pickled tagger), and keep it where the nltk can find it next time. You don't say why it's not found. Doesn't `C:\Users\Client\nltk_data\taggers\maxent_treebank_pos_tagger\english.pickle` persist across runs?

Comment: what is your output for `python -c "import nltk; print nltk.__version__"`?